# Dictionary in wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have an WCF service which contains a method that returns a Dictionary.

The generated method in the proxy class returns      ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring array.
how can i use this method ?

The contract method :

```
        [OperationContract]
        Dictionary<string, string> GetESGKeywordQuestion();

In the proxy class i have 

ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[] GetESGKeywordQuestion()
{
// code
}
```

Comment: you want to pass the dictionary inside this method and return as array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953808/why-cant-wcf-pass-an-object-in-a-dictionary possibly discusses the same issue.

Comment: i can not understand why the generated method in the proxy class returns ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring array and not a Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>` is specific to c#. The WSDL needs to describe the return type in a way other languages (PHP, JAVA, VB.net, etc) can understand. A `Dictionary<string,string>` can also be described as an array of `KeyValuePair<string,string>` objects. It's likely this is what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accepted answer in another similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953808/why-cant-wcf-pass-an-object-in-a-dictionary) reference to a link [telling you how to have Dictionary at the client side](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,ff5fab81-affb-4b2b-aa67-c80bdfc86cbd.aspx) 
in .NET to .NET communication. In other words, poor interoperability if you want your service to be consumed by non-dot-net applications like PHP or Java etc. If you had learned/remember data structure in CS, you know dictionary is implemented through non-linear structure like B-tree, so dictionary is not likely to be included in WSDL because of the complexity and variant.  The ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring structure generated for client is well designed and intended. If you want to see consistency on both side and want interoperability, then don't use Dictionary, instead, use a linear structure such as an array of KeyValuePair.

Answer (score 0):

the generated proxy class seems to be wrong..

Try changing it to return the required `Dictionary` manually..

```
Dictionary<string, string> GetESGKeywordQuestion()
{
    //code
}
```

And this should allow you to use you `GetESGKeywordQuestion()` method from your WCF service

Comment: but why the generated proxy class is wrong ? and why i have ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring array and not ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring

Comment: but why i have to update the proxy manualy, why the return type is not the same ?

Comment: may be because you have made changes in the WCF service and not updated the proxy. That is why I asked you, have you updated the proxy?

Comment: I doubt that, if that were the case the proxy would have the correct return type for the GetESGKeywordQuestion() method

Comment: the returned type in the proxy method was replaced by ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring arrayn the ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring class contains 2 properties key and value, which is represents the dictionary

Comment: the dictionary was replaced by ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring, and that's working fine, but why this changes ?

Comment: This is the last time I am repeating. Because the signature in the Proxy should match the signature in the Service. Clearly the proxy is not up to date, so we manually changed the signature to match with the signature of the service's method.